# Iteration over Excel column indices in PHP

Tags: php, excel, iteration

I fill an Excel sheet in my PHP script using [a Microsoft library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheet.aspx). I use a column index and a row index to address a certain cell. Iterating over rows is no problem as they have numeric indices. However, for now I don't know how many columns I will have in advance. I would start from column *D* and then I need to address columns *E, F, G*... consequently. I don't know the last index in advance, it can be any of one- or double-letter index, like *AA* or *BD*... So, what is the best way to iterate over such indices consisting of latin letters as in Excel documents?

Comment: I have not tried this with Excel but used an alpha index in another project by setting my index as: `$i = 'A';`  and in my loop using `$i++;` it counted up Excel-style. A,B,C...Z,AA,AB,AC etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Steve, the solution is as simple as

```
$i='D';            
for( $j=0; $j<1000; $j++) {
  echo ($i.' ') ;
  $i++;
}
```

To iterate over Latin letters Excel-style one only needs to initialize a variable with the first index and then increment it before usage in each iteration.

Comment: If the data you are putting into the sheet is held in an array, you could use `count($your_excel_data_array);` to give you a fixed top value for `j` but you did say you don't know how many columns you will have in advance so that may not be of any use.